# Recording cell history, stop recording cell history if record exceeds N rows

Tags: excel, vba, cell, history

So far I have the code needed to write the cell history to a new row, but am missing what is needed to stop writing cell history once I have gathered the desired amount of values. I would like for the macro to stop recording cell history once it has stored 100 or 1000 values

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim sDate As Worksheet
Dim nNewRow As Long

Set sData = Worksheets("sheet1")
nNewRow = sData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
sData.Cells(nNewRow, 1).Value = sData.Range("A1").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a check to nNewRow and only perform the `sData.Cells(nNewRow...` operation if it's less than N rows

Comment: For example: `If nNewRow < 100 Then`

Comment: Also, as a note, you have Dim *sDate*, but then you Set *sData*, looks like a typo.  May want to Dim it as *sData* so that it all matches and the variable is declared properly.  You can avoid these kind of typo errors by turning on [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)

Comment: I'm new to using VBA so I might be misunderstanding something fundamental but I'm not able to get the if/then check to work. No errors are reported in the code but when I continued to generate values the cell history continued to record beyond the specified limit.

Comment: I simply added: If nNewRow < 10 then above nNewRow=sData.Cell(Row..) and added Else End If underneath the following line

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.  Note that you don't have to define the sheet, the passed `Sh` object variable does that for you, just specify which sheet to check.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Dim nNewRow As Long

    'Disable events to prevent infinite loops
    Application.enableevents = False

    'Verify we are working with Sheet1
    If LCase(Sh.Name) = "sheet1" Then
        'Check the value of nNewRow
        nNewRow = Sh.Cells(Sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If nNewRow <= 10 Then
            'Within threshold, record value
            Sh.Cells(nNewRow, 1).Value = Sh.Range("A1").Value
        End If
    End If

    'Turn events back on
    Application.enableevents = True

End Sub
```